# How do I use certificate-based authentication with WATIR-WebDriver?

Tags: certificate, watir, watir-webdriver

I've been using ruby Mechanize for several years to do automated testing of the SaaS product we host. The site is using JS more and more, making maintenance of the Mechanize scripts nearly impossible. I've decided to try using WATIR-WebDriver instead. However, the login process requires a user certificate and password. I can't find any reference to using a cert like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Chrome, you can ignore certificate errors by passing an command line option to the Chrome Driver:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
```

If you're using Firefox, try

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = true
b = Watir::Browser.new WEB_DRIVER, :profile => profile
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about host certificates. I'm talking about user certs for authorization. When I access the site, it asks me to choose the user cert from installed certs, and then prompts for a password via basic auth. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: what about if you are using IE?